# Section title running into margin

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, sections-paragraphs

In the below MWE one can see that the section title runs into the margin of the page. This is due to the use of the `\mbox{...}`, but the `\mbox` is unfortunately in the normal case, automatically generated text, necessary.

Edit:
The `\mbox` cannot be broken across lines, but is it possible to break the line before the `\mbox`?

How to prevent that the section title runs into the margin?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Index}
\section{image more text even more format file caption \mbox{some more text even}}
image more text even some more text even more format file caption some more text even
image more text even some more text even more format file caption some more text even
image more text even some more text even more format file caption some more text even

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: It is sort of a feature of `\mbox` that it forms an unbreakable unit. As such it would be expected that it does not allow for line breaks (neither in section titles nor anywhere else). If you want to allow for line breaks I suggest you try to go to the source and avoid `\mbox` being used/generated. (Theoretically you could redefine what `\mbox` does, but I guess this could cause many more problems than it potentially solves. Redefining standard commands is rarely a good idea.)

Comment: It is clear that `\mbox` cannot be broken, but would it be possible that the line-break takes place before the `\mbox`, I've edited this into the question.

Comment: Be aware that in case of using the hyperref-package, you might need `\texorpdfstring` or the like for adjusting the text that occurs in the bookmarks of your pdf-file. (The text in the bookmarks in the pdf-file will be processed by the pdf-viewing-program, not by LaTeX. The pdf-viewing-program will most likely not "understand" things like `\mbox`-commands .) But maybe you needn't care as `\mbox` is already one of the `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`-thingies...

Comment: In case the functionality of the `\mbox` is not needed but the `\mbox`-command is there due to automatic generation of text, you can probably within a local scope redefine the `\mbox`-command to just spit out the argument... When doing this be aware that `\mbox`-commands might also "slip" into moving arguments (entries of the table of contents, entries for `\label`-`\nameref`-references, page-headers etc) while a local redefinition of `\mbox` probably does not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `\sloppy` and `\raggedright` are your friends.

---

`\sloppy` without `\raggedright`:

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Index}
\begingroup
\sloppy
%\raggedright
\section{image more text even more format file caption \mbox{some more text even}}\par
\endgroup
image more text even some more text even more format file caption some more text even
image more text even some more text even more format file caption some more text even
image more text even some more text even more format file caption some more text even

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

`\sloppy` and `\raggedright`:

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Index}
\begingroup
\sloppy
\raggedright
\section{image more text even more format file caption \mbox{some more text even}}\par
\endgroup
image more text even some more text even more format file caption some more text even
image more text even some more text even more format file caption some more text even
image more text even some more text even more format file caption some more text even

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks promising, I'll do some tests later on with this on the original source.

Comment: Be aware that section headings are moving arguments. They do not occur only in the main text. They also appear in the table of contents and probably in page-headers and with pdf-files with hyperlinks they may appear in the bookmarks. They may also be delivered by `\nameref`. You may need to apply `\sloppy` (and `\raggedright`) to the table of contents / to other places where these section headings occur,  as well... Perhaps you can convince your automatic text generator not to deliver `\mbox` but something like`\mycmd` so you can in any place locally redefine `\mycmd`  according to your needs.

Comment: Unless you remove the formatting in the optional argument (short title).